# Modsec ruleRemoveTargetById is not removing rules

Tags: mod-security2

I am trying to write modsecurity rule exclusions and cant seem to get `ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById` to work as per the reference manual.

My server is running Debian 9 with apache2 2.4.25-3+deb9 I have tried following the reference manual on github and tried emulating the sample rules in the file >REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf. I have written a simple rule to fire on certain arguments and then tried excluding it, but it wont exclude the rule based on the arguments. I can see both the rule id and the rule exclusion id in the logs.

I have, arbitrarily, put the below rule in REQUEST-905-COMMON-EXCEPTIONS.conf

```
SecRule ARGS "@rx propfind" "id:905999,phase:2,log,msg:'test msg delete rule'"
```

This fires as it should. There is an argument named `<?xml version` that contains the pattern "propfind" in my nextcloud settings page, which I am using for testing.

I have also written an exclusion and put it into REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf

```
SecRule ARGS_NAMES "@rx <\?xml\sversion" "phase:2,log,id:1030,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=905999;ARGS:/<\?xml\sversion/"
```

This rule triggers as expected but does not prevent rule 905999 from firing on argument named `<?xml version`

I have simplified the rules to the two below and it works as expected; when I enter `example.com/?test=trigger` I see rule 905999 in the log, but if I send `example.com/?testarg=trigger` I only see the exclusion rule 1030 as expected.

```
SecRule ARGS "@rx trigger" "id:905999,phase:2,log,msg:'test msg delete rule'"

SecRule ARGS_NAMES "@rx testarg" "phase:2,log,id:1030,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=905999;ARGS:testarg"
```

When I open the nextcloud settings tab the HTTP request contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:"><d:prop><d:resourcetype/></d:prop></d:propfind>
```

which Modsec interprets as the argument name `<?xml version`, containing the value `"1.0"?><d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:"><d:prop><d:resourcetype/></d:prop></d:propfind>`

I would expect my rule 1030 to stop 905999 from firing, but i still see both rules in the log. I am assuming it is because of the space between "xml" and "version" but cant figure out how to exclude the target.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the regex in `ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=905999;ARGS:/<\?xml\sversion/` did not work. Using `SecRuleUpdateTargetById 905999 "!ARGS:/<\?xml\sversion"` and placing it into `RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf` to update the rule targets after they are loaded works as desired.